# How to insert the author of a quotation using natbib and lyx?

Tags: lyx, natbib

Hello all: have a small issue, (btw, i am quite new to LaTeX, so please be gentle :))

When I create a quote in lyx and add a reference to it:

```
% Preview source code for paragraph 52

\begin{quote}
``A software bug is the common term used to describe an error, flaw,
mistake, failure, or fault in a computer program or system that produces
an incorrect or unexpected result, or causes it to behave in unintended
ways.''\citet*{WIKIPEDIA:2012:SoftwareBug}
\end{quote}
```

I expect it to generate the quote with the **(author?)** filled in from the bibliography entry.  The bibliography entry definitely has the author field filled out.  However I keep on getting this:

[image: Rendered with (author?)]

I am using the article(ams) layout.

What could I be doing wrong? Am I missing how authors are pulled out?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

The BibTex for the citation is:

```
@url{WIKIPEDIA:2012:SoftwareBug,
    Author = {WikiPedia},
    Date-Added = {2012-01-05 05:31:03 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2012-01-05 07:13:51 +0000},
    Howpublished = {Internet},
    Journal = {Wikipedia},
    Keywords = {Software Bug},
    Lastchecked = {January 1, 2012},
    Local-Url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug},
    Month = {January},
    Rating = {4},
    Read = {1},
    Title = {Software Bug},
    Url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug},
    Urldate = {2012},
    Year = {2012}}
```

Comment: Are you maybe inadvertently using a numeric rather than an author-year bibliography style file? Since you're using the `amsart` document class, be sure to either issue the command `\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}` as well or to explicitly load another author-year bibliography style file that's compatible with `natbib` and `amsart`.

Comment: Aaah... Okay yes my bibliography style is indeed numerical, as a matter of fact I am using natbib style and a custom-bib style (using merlin) ... So i should generate an author-year style (mine is numerical)

Comment: I'm glad it turns out that it's so easy to fix this issue. I'll convert my comment to an official answer, just so that this question can be checked off as "answered." I'll also modify the title of your question to make it reflect more accurately what your question is about.

Comment: follow up question if i may then, is it possible to pull out the author in numerical form (since that is my preferred reference style) by redefining the quote?  --- Whoops never mind I think i can figure that out -- re-Whoops, so can i redefine and use `citet` instead of `citet*`?

Comment: I'm afraid you've got me quite confused. Are you thinking of using the "plain old" `\cite` command along with a numeric-style bibliography style file? That'll certainly work. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you maybe inadvertently using a bibliography style file that uses a numeric rather than an author/year labeling system? Since you're using the `amsart` document class, be sure to either issue the command

```
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
```

or to employ some other author/year-type bibliography style file that's compatible with `natbib`. (Since you're using the command `citet*`, I'm assuming you've loaded `natbib`...)